# Function working in single.php but not working in custom template file

Tags: functions, front-end, wp-update-post

I defined in my functions.php the following code:

```
function fix_footnotes($content){

          return preg_replace('/href\s*=\s*"[^"]+(#[^"]+)"/','href="$1"', $content); 

}
```

When I call this function in single.php, it is performing well. I use:

```
<?php echo fix_footnotes(get_the_content());?>
```

But when I call it inside of `wp_update_post` in custom template, it doesn't work. The template is responsible of updating posts from front end:

```
$post_information = array(
        'ID' => $current_post,
        'post_content' => fix_footnotes($_POST['contentEditorBox']),
        'post_type' => 'aya-bi-aya',
        'post_status' => 'publish'
    );

$post_id = wp_update_post($post_information);
```

What can be the reasons behind such disfunctionning. Your assistance is highly invaluable.Thank you.

**Edit**:

**S_HA_DUM:** when I var_dump `$_POST['contentEditorBox']` it gives me the correct result. This is representing what `wp_editor` sends to server:

```
wp_editor($content, 'contentEditorBox', $settings2 );
```

**Edit 2:**
Following is a sample of my content in  `$_POST['contentEditorBox']`  and `$content` respectively:

```
<p class="\&quot;MsoNormal\&quot;" dir="\&quot;RTL\&quot;" style="\&quot;text-align:" center;="" direction:="" rtl;="" unicode-bidi:="" embed;\"="" align="\&quot;center\&quot;"><span lang="\&quot;AR-KW\&quot;" style="\&quot;font-size:" 16.0pt;="" line-height:="" 115%;="" font-family:="" \'simplified="" arabic\',\'serif\';="" mso-bidi-language:="" ar-kw;\"="">التحليل البلاغي للآيات رقم :49-51 من سورة المدثر.</span></p>


<p class="MsoNormal" dir="RTL" style="text-align: center; direction: rtl; unicode-bidi: embed;" align="center"><span lang="AR-KW" style="font-size: 16.0pt; line-height: 115%; font-family: 'Simplified Arabic','serif'; mso-bidi-language: AR-KW;">التحليل البلاغي للآيات رقم :49-51 من سورة المدثر.</span></p>
```

As you can see, everything is wrapped by `\&quot`. What I don't undersrand, is that after sending the form the content appears as it should be. In other words, the adding of `\&quot` is temporary, it happens only inside `$_POST['contentEditorBox']` but not persisted in database. Any insights?

Comment: What have you done to debug? How does the output of the function change based on the two uses?

Comment: No reason it shouldn't work if passed similar information, so I am going to guess that `$_POST['contentEditorBox']` isn't what you think it is.

Comment: What have you done to debug *your specific problem*? If the server debug log isn't relevant, there's no need to include it in your question. Debugging *your specific problem* would include comparing output/return values at various points in the process, to see where the data differ between the functioning example and the non-functioning example.

Comment: Post a small part of the content of `$_POST['contentEditorBox']` that you think should be altered by your `fix_footnotes` function.

Comment: @s_ha_dum. Thank you for checking this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19752764/preg-replace-second-parameter-replacement-doesnt-fit?noredirect=1#comment29352834_19752764. It is explainining well what should be altered by `fix_footnotes`. `$_POST['contentEditorBox']` is containg what is sent by `wp_editor` after editing what `get_the_content` returns.

Comment: Well I found that there is a difference between `$content` and `$_POST['contentEditorBox'] `. Those are not the same and this is what is causing the problem.

Comment: "*Well I found that...*" - please **edit your question** to include such findings, including the specific differences. Such information tends to get lost in the comments.

Comment: @ChipBennett I am doing it, it is just that I am slow in my actions. Thank you for your time and assistance. I will also provide with a detailed solution as an answer.

Comment: In the edit, I provided a var_dump of `$content` and `$_POST['contentEditorBox']`.